# How to change scianimator delay parameter from within RMarkdown?

Tags: r, jquery-animate, knitr

I'm creating an RMarkdown presentation (ioslides), and it contains an animation. I've successfully used hook_scianimator, by using an external header to include the css and js files necessary. However, I can't tell how or where I can modify scianimator parameters.

In the following example, I have set the afp parameter in render() to 1/19, and am making 190 frames. So, hopefully I can make an animation with 10 seconds of animation at 19 frames per second.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "June 23, 2015"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    includes:
       in_header: header.html
    self_contained: false
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(animation.fun = hook_scianimator, cache=TRUE)
knit_hooks$set(custom_plot = hook_plot_custom)
```

```{r tourr, custom_plot=TRUE, fig.show='animate', fig.ext='png', echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, out.width='2.5in',fig.num=190}
library(tourr)
tourr::render(flea[, 1:6], grand_tour(d = 2), display = display_xy(), frames=190, apf=1/19, dev="png", fig_path("%1d.png"), width=240, height=240)
Sys.sleep(1)
```
````

However, when I inspect the HTML that is generated by Knit HTML, I see the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var imgs = Array(190);
       for (i = 0; ; i++) {
         if (i == imgs.length) break;
        imgs[i] = "Presentation_files/figure-html/tourr-" + (i + 1) + ".png";
      }
      $("#tourr").scianimator({
           "images": imgs,
           "delay": 1000,
          "controls": ["first", "previous", "play", "next", "last", "loop", "speed"],
      });
      $("#tourr").scianimator("play");
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

The relevant component is the `"delay": 1000,`. This is not the scianimator default ([that number is 250](https://github.com/brentertz/scianimator#readme)). And, since there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, that delay means it is playing one frame per second.

How can I pass my preferred delay? Is it within a knitr option, either at the document or chunk level? Should I be hand-editing the HTML? Can I change something in the javascript somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it, but I guess the chunk option `interval` should work, e.g. `interval = 0.25` (250 milliseconds).